# Why update clause updates primary key index

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I have query

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE (
    id BIGINT
);
DECLARE @dtDateLimit DATETIME;
SET @dtDateLimit = DATEADD(MINUTE, (-1) * @ResignTimeout, GETDATE());

UPDATE queue_local
SET [status] = @QueueLocalStatusToSign
OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @ids
WHERE [status] = @QueueLocalStatusSigning
AND status_date < @dtDateLimit;
```

According to execution plan this clause updates primary key index (on column "id").
Is there a reason for this behavior?

I'm asking because I have deadlock on this index with the similar update

```
UPDATE TOP (1) queue_local
SET [status] =
                CASE
                    WHEN @SignError IS NULL THEN @QueueLocalStatusSigned
                    ELSE @QueueLocalStatusError
                END
OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @ql_ids
WHERE task_sign_id = @ts_id
AND sono = @Sono
AND [status] = @QueueLocalStatusSigning
```

I try to understand server behavior

Comment: What's the clustered index on the table? (For that matter, what are all of the indexes on the table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the execution plan. Do you see the Operator Clustered Index Update? If you have a table with a clustered index then the clustered index containts the whole table. So it needs always to be updated.
On the other hand this doesn't mean, that the clustered index KEY will be updated. If, in your case, the column [status] is not part of your clustered index key, only the leaf Level of the clustered index will be updated for the matching rows. (if no page splits occur).

If you have a nonclustered index on the [Status] column, then SQL Server can lookup the entry point (id) to the clustered index from there.